# Transfer files between host and guest using virtio-serial

Tags: windows, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have a Windows 10 guest with very limited network access (limited by Check-Point VPN firewall) which I access through the spice viewer.
 
But I need to transfer files to/from the guest.
I tried to setup Folder Sharing (a function of the virt remote spice viewer) but even that seemed to be blocked by the guest firewall (cannot access the webdavd service).
I assume my only option is to use the virtio-serial as this will not use network.
My first problem is to define a channel in the virt XML file:

```
<channel type='unix'>
   <source type='bind' path='/tmp/foo'/>
   <target type='virtio' port='0'/>
</channel>
```

But I get the error

```
error: XML document failed to validate against schema: Unable to validate doc against /usr/share/libvirt/schemas/domain.rng
Extra element devices in interleave
Element domain failed to validate content
```

Any help are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A new solution is under development:  [virtio-fs](https://virtio-fs.gitlab.io).
Not using network but FUSE.

Still not sure if it's usable in Windows guests.

PDF: [Virtio-fs for Kata Containers storage](https://vmsplice.net/~stefan/stefanha-virtio-fs-kata.pdf)

Comment: it is not usable in windows guests yet:  `I have not thought much about making it work on Windows or BSD yet.`  [source](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/20181210171318.16998-1-vgoyal@redhat.com/t/#r2773db0dc95b25d8fc10713c65f943e7df004d99)

Comment: It was also a bad idea. 
I managed to reach the VM by network overruling the IP routes created by the VPN client. Although I can only access it using FTP, not SMB share.